# Change color of a SVG in Favicon

Tags: javascript, html, svg, colors, favicon

I want to change the color of a SVG that I use as a FavIcon in an HTML-Page.
I want to use a button and if you click the button it should change the FavIcon.

I already got it to work with normal SVG elements on my page, but I can not find a way that work for FavIcon.

Anybody have an idea about how to do it?

Comment: I could be wrong, but svg uses internal styles and sandboxed, therefore there is no way change it's style externally, you'd need modify svg file itself. Personally, I use php for this

Comment: Technically you can parse the contents of an svg file, and then do something with the code, and then use the results in a Data URI.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="image-name.svg" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
```

create two icons and replace using js function.

```
<button class="btn2" type="button" onclick="changeFavicon()"> Change Favicon </button>


// Assign a constant variable and get them by the favicon Id
const favicon = document.getElementById("favicon");

// Creating a function for the button
function changeFavicon() {
    favicon.setAttribute("href", "image-name2.svg"); 
}
```